# Intellij autofix eslint on save feature is unreliable with ReactJS CRA app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, eslint

Working with ReactJS built with Create-React-App (CRA) using Javascript (not Typescript) and whenever I enable the Autofix Eslint in IntelliJ, it works for awhile but will eventually stop from autofixing, making it very unreliable.

Versions:

React v17

CRA v5

Eslint v8.84

IntelliJ 2021.3.1 Ultimate Edition

Is there anything I am missing with this IntelliJ setup?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please attach the logs from the language service?
To collect service logs please go to **Help | Diagnostic Tools | Debug Log Settings…** and add `#com.intellij.lang.javascript.service.JSLanguageServiceQueue:trace` to the Custom Debug Configuration window.
Then restart the IDE, reproduce the issue, and send us all the IDE logs collected via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data….

Also, please clarify if the error highlighting continues working after the auto-fix stops.